# Selecting div ID in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please go easy, this is my first bs4 webscraper! I'm trying to select a div ID for the price on a second hand goods website. This is the inspect element section of the price box:

```
  <div class="price-box">

  <div id="priceBox-price" class="price" itemprop="price" content="879,00">

                €&nbsp;879,-         
    </div>
```

This is my python code:

```
import requests
import bs4

def scrape_site(url):                       
    res = requests.get()
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find("div", class_= "price")
    print(price)
```

`print(price)` returns 'none'. I've tried passing numerous class IDs and other div IDs to `soup.find` or `soup.select` but unfortunately I just can't seem to be able to extract the number from the box.

I would also like to select numerous other elements on this page and add them to an already initialised globally available list. Is it more effective to pass `soup.find` multiple class IDs (or whatever the solution here is) or to have numerous lines that append the found `soup` object to the list?

Here is an example of an ad that I would like to extract price, colour, location and date modified/posted from:

https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/serious-valparola-pro-rennrad-422463471/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit:

the `.get` doesn't work regardless of what variables I change around. Here is my full current code and all the function returns (without the `.get`) is "None"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#list initialisation for data storage

name = []
address = []
colour = []
price = []
last_edited = []


def scrape_site(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') #.get('content')
    price = soup.find('div',{'itemprop':'price'})
    print(price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [51]: from bs4 import *

In [52]: soup = BeautifulSoup('''  <div class="price-box">
    ...:
    ...:   <div id="priceBox-price" class="price" itemprop="price" content="879,00">
    ...:
    ...:                 &nbsp;879,-
    ...:     </div>''', 'html.parser')

In [53]: soup.find('div',{'itemprop':'price'}).get('content')
Out[53]: '879,00'
```

Based on your comment:

```
import pandas ad pd
data = []
list_of_ad_urls = ['url1','url2', 'url3']
for url in list_of_ad_urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    required_item_1 = soup.find(logic to find element 1)
    price = soup.find('div',{'itemprop':'price'}).get('content')
    required_item_3 = soup.find(logic to find element 3)
    data.append([required_item_1, required_item_2, required_item_3])

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('mydata.csv', index=False, header='h1,h2,h3'.split(','))
```

Comment: is there any way I can adapt this so that I don't have to pass in the actual HTML in my code? I want to scrape up to 100 ads, take numerous elements from the page, store them in lists then import the data into an excel file

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much for your help. One more thing: I'm getting an AttributeError on the `.get` in the price line.

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Make sure that BeautifulSoup object is successfully created and then make sure that 
    soup.find('div', {'itemprop':'price'}) returns an element. From the error in your comment, it apperas that no object with this itemprop in div is found.

Comment: I've tried what feels like everything I know to this point. Could you please have a look at my edit in the main post?

Comment: I have had a look. The problem is with the website. You can see the same element when you inspect but the source code is different. The item price etc is loaded at runtime using a json object which is also in the page.

Comment: but I don't have access to the json object right? Sorry for all the stupid questions, this is quite literally my first project

Comment: For each page, download the page using requests, prepare a BeautifulSoup object and call it soup and then use this line of code to extract all data fields from one line. This will return a json object. `json.loads(soup.findAll('script')[16].text.strip().split('=')[1].split('\n')[0][:-1].strip())['tmsData']`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Ibrahim! I'll give that a go and hopefully I can get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Try just changing this line

```py
price = soup.find("div", class_= "price")
```

to this

```py
price = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":'price'})
```

Comment: Now it just returns an empty list [ ]